# Gradle publishing jar into nexus repo

Tags: gradle

Q： Task 'publishAllPublicationsToSnapshotRepository' not found in root project

img：[erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5X7p.png)

build.sh:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ve5Oq.png)

Answer (score 0):

you have to include the maven-publish plugin

```
plugins {
    id 'maven-publish'
}
```

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven